# What, within my web access, is caching web pages so aggressively?

Tags: browser-cache

Something along the path of my home internet access is caching web content aggressively, and maybe you can help tell me where it is.

Here is my example:

1. I made a very simple web page, consisting of an index.html and two photos. I used FTP to place them inside a directory off on my typical web host (the inexpensive bluehost, similar to other cheapies like goDaddy.)
2. However, I made a mistake and, when I first uploaded the files, I mistakenly still had the index html file named something like indexjobs.html
3. Naturally, when I went over to Firefox browser and navigated to the URL of the directory I had created, it did not load the page (since the file was not called index) but instead it simply displayed the full contents of that directory... i.e., the two image files, the indexjob.html... you know, the regular "browser page displaying a server directory" page.
4. So, I hopped over to my FTP client and renamed indexjobs.html to index.html.
5. I went to firefox and hit reload -- it still showed the directory page, instead of launching the index file... and still displayed the outdated indexjobs.html file name.
6. I issued the firefox command to clear its cache. And hit reload on that URL.  It still showed the directory page and the outdated indexjobs.html filename.
7. Then, I went to load that URL in ANOTHER BROWSER, namely Chrome, on my same mac, and even though that browser had never before loaded that page, IT showed the directory page with the outdated indexjobs.html filename!  Though that file had long since been renamed!  It must have been going to some cache other than firefox's cache...
8. I believe that I then went to an adjacent laptop (a windows laptop) and went to load that URL on IE 10 for windows, and it did not show the directory page but rather loaded the page -- in other words, it recognized that the file had been renamed to index.html
9. Viewing the page on IE made me see one small error that I made on that page, so I went and used FTP to change the index.html file to fix that error.  Then I went back to IE and hit reload.  It did not show me the fixed version.  Then I cleared IE's cache and hit reload. It STILL did not show me the fixed version. I then decided to change the name of the directory that was holding this simple page... which thus of course changed its URL. When I loaded that new URL in IE, of course, it reflected the change correctly.

Where is this aggressive caching taking place?  In step #7 up there it seemed to point to the idea that the mac had some cache in its OS that was delivering content to both browsers (though I doubt that.)   Or, another possibility is that there is caching done by my ISP, but when I went over to my separate laptop, it somehow caused that ISP cache to recognize a different internal IP address (?? but these are all served by a single router...) ... or a different... OK, in short, I do not know.

What is caching my web this way?

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a case of ISP cache or proxy cache.

Replicate the scenario (no cache clearing) in Firefox and then you can check the http response headers to see from which cache the request is being served from. use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to open the web console in Firefox and check the response headers for cache info.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a decade old, but I've been struggling with it for a long time. Today, I finally discovered a solution!

I use a Mac, but I sure the solution is similar for other OS. I clicked the Wi-Fi icon in the corner and selected "Wi-Fi Settings". From there, I can see a dialog box that has a tab labeled "DNS". Now I can see some IP addresses.

The solution is to remove those IP addresses which forces my machine to create new ones that do not have the cached sites on them!